# $this->referer does not work properly in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have an action called 'run' in the controller 'tests', I want to re run the action with the same parameter as passed in the first run.

for example /tests/run/6 , I want to run the same (/tests/run/6) once the form input is submitted, while I am  able to run this on my local server using $this->redirect($this->referer()) in the action but not able to do so on my hostgator VPS server, it rather goes to /tests/run and not /tests/run/6

What am I doing wrong here, I tried $this->redirect(array('action'=>'tests',$id)) but this is running /tests/run and not /tests/run/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you use 1.3 where the form does not automatically post to itself (as opposed to 2.0 where I recommended that and where it was introduced).

you need to use url in this case:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Model', array('url'=>'/'.$this->params['url']['url']));?>
```

Comment: mark, could you expatiate please , I am sort of a rookie,in the url part what should be $this->params['url']['url']